Flow - Text fields with defined variables e.g. {!$Record.FieldName__c}
I have a Flow that is triggering when specific checkbox field is selected.
Then Flow takes values from fields on triggering Lead and sends text message.
E.g. In order to insert First Name of the lead on text message I use:
{!$Record.FirstName}

But I want to define text messages content in another custom object.
So I enter in text field :
"Hello {!$Record.FirstName} please call us at..."

Then reference it in the Flow...
But it is not working since {!$Record.FirstName} is treated as text not variable reference.
Is there a way to accomplish it?

Formula field is what you want: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields

The goal here is that any user (not SF admin) can modify text template. With Formula fields SF admin always has to be involved.

They'd be modifying the field storing your text message rather than the formula field. Ex: formula field is concatenate field1 and field2, field1 is 'Hello ' and field2 is 'please call us at...'

use a Message Template in the flow, not a text variable

@user3299199

Create any text variable and assign message content and store it in custom object

In my Flow, I created a text variable called message1, then I used assignment {!message1} Equals {!getRecord.Template1__c}.
This “Template1__c” on custom object Template is equal to “Hello {!$Record.FirstName} please call us at...”
Result
{!message1} = “Hello {!$Record.FirstName} please call us at...”
as oppose to FirstName pulled from triggering Record (Lead)
